# Android Sensor recording values simultaneously

Tags: android, events, android-sensors

Im building an application which has to record various sensor values simulatneously into a .csv file(if sensors are available).Can any one suggest ways to keep inserting values into the csv file(of a table form).Is it possible to record all the .csv values in a single sensor change event.

Anva

Comment: I am not really understanding this question, are you asking how to synchronize sensor outputs, or are you asking a question about inserting data?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write the data in the event handler of the Sensor?

Comment: thank you for your time....i need to record all the sensors(accl,prox.,gps etc.) simultaeously...

Comment: I don't fully understand but consider using a Queue of some sort to get the data out of your sensor handler thread. Writing I/O can be a relatively long process.

Answer (score 2):

You can only receive data from 1 sensor at a time, and the sensors may be reporting data at different time intervals.

There are several ways you could approach this.

The simplest would be to cache the values for each sensor, and then whenever you get new data for any sensor, you update the cached value for that sensor and then write a new CSV line with all of the cached sensor values. This new line of CSV will only differ from the previous for the 1 sensor whose data you just updated.

```
(Pseudo-code)
onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    //Note: in practice, you need to copy the values out of the event.values array
    //using, for example, System.arraycopy
    cached_values[event.sensor.getType()] = event.values; 
    writeCsvLine(cached_values);
}
```

Alternatively, instead of writing a line of CSV every time you get a piece of data, you could cache the sensor values until you get a "duplicate" - i.e. data for a sensor that you already have unwritten data for. Then you would write out a CSV line for the cached values, reset your "is_written" flags for each sensor, and update the cached value for the sensor you just got. This way, you don't have as many duplicate values in the CSV file, but are still guaranteed to not miss any reported sensor value.

```
(Pseudo-code)
onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (!cached_value_written[event.sensor.getType()]) {
       writeCsvLine(cached_values);
       cached_values_written.reset(); //reset all flags to true
    }
    cached_values[event.sensor.getType()] = event.values; 
    cached_value_written[event.sensor.getType()] = false;
}
```

Yet another approach would be to cache the sensor values as you get them, and then in a separate thread, you would grab the "current" values every, say, 1 second, and write them out. In this approach, you need to be careful to synchronize access to the cached values, because you would be reading and writing in separate threads.

```
(Pseudo-code)
onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    synchronized(cached_values) {
        cached_values[event.sensor.getType()] = event.values;
    }
}

//on a separate thread:
run() {
   while (true) {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       synchronized(cached_values) {
           writeCsvLine(cached_values);               
       }
   }
}
```

Or, instead of having a separate thread that checks every 1 second, you could store the time at which you last wrote the values, and then when you get in a new value, check if 1 second (or whatever interval you want to use) has elapsed since the last time you wrote data, and if so, write a new CSV line with the currently cached values.

```
(Pseudo-code)
onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    cached_values[event.sensor.getType()] = event.values;
    if (currentTime - lastWrittenTime >= 1000) {
        writeCsvLine(cached_values);
        lastWrittenTime = currentTime;
    }
}
```